# Rotating square causes stretching

Tags: java, rotation, geometry

I'm currently working on a geometric engine(in which I hope to build a physics, and game engine upon)... and it has an issue. When I rotate a rectangle, say a square, it turns it into a diamondish shape first, then it goes almost invisible, and then back to a square.

```
for(int i = 0; i < fv.length; i++) {
    double[] ve = fv[i];
    ve[0] = ve[0] - getCMX();
    ve[1] = ve[1] - getCMY();
    double sin = Math.sin(getRot());
    double cos = Math.cos(getRot());
    ve[0] = ((cos * ve[0]) - (sin * ve[1]));
    ve[1] = ((-sin * ve[0]) + (cos * ve[1]));
    ve[0] = ve[0] + getCMX();
    ve[1] = ve[1] + getCMY();
    fv[i] = ve;
}
```

fv is a 2D double array.
getCMX/CMY gets the center of the square.

Any thoughts are appreciated, my goal is to have the square keep the same area while rotating...?

Comment: Hi.  Asking people to spot errors in your code is not especially productive. You should use the debugger (or add print statements) to isolate the problem, by tracing the progress of your program, and comparing it to what you expect to happen. As soon as the two diverge, then you've found your problem. (And then if necessary, you should construct a [minimal test-case](http://sscce.org).)

Comment: Yes, well this is more a mathematics than a code issue(in my opinion). As someone who taught themselves geometry, I'm not sure what to expect, but I'm assuming that what that gets me is not correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your two sin factors need to have opposite signs.  And you have to use an unaltered copy of ve[0] to update ve[1]:

```
temp  = ((cos * ve[0]) - (sin * ve[1]));
ve[1] = ((sin * ve[0]) + (cos * ve[1]));
ve[0] = temp;
```

Comment: My negation of sin just reverses the direction of rotation. Without it, the problem still persists.

Comment: You also have to save a temporary copy of ve[0] for use in updating ve[1].

Comment: Alright, if that conserves shape, then why does at certain rotations, the square become a line... or disappear altogether, and expand back into a square? I changed it to what you said, and there was no change.

Answer (score 1):

Two problems:

1. You can't compute the result into the same vector as the source.  Use two vectors.
2. The right transform is  x' = c * x - s * y;  y' = s * x + c * y;